# Is there anything like Python Itertools in Perl?

Tags: python, perl, python-itertools

Python has [great module for working with iterators called itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) Is there any analog in Perl?

I know about [Object-Iterate](https://github.com/briandfoy/Object-Iterate) but it has only imap and igrep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[List::Gen](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen) does a lot of that.

Comment: Very interesting module, thank you. What version of Perl does it require?

Answer (score 4):

While I don't know exactly what iterators you need, [CPAN is full of them](https://metacpan.org/search?q=iterator), it really depends on what you need. I needed iterators over all the combinations possible in an array: there's a [CPAN module for that](https://metacpan.org/module/Algorithm%3a%3aCombinatorics).